# Filter command output using grep

Tags: logging, grep

I have a command line program that I am using, which logs to the console. However, do to some buggy firmware, it prints a certain error every 1 seconds.

How can I use `grep` to filter the output so that this one specific error line is omitted from being logged to the console?

The exact error I want to get rid of is:

```
[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned
```

If I create an `sh` script with the offending line in it, like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned"
echo "testing"
```

And then run it, the output is, as expected,

```
[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned
testing
```

Now, if I run it using `grep -v` to try to omit this line, like so:

```
./script.sh | grep -v "[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned"
```

The output is still:

```
[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned
testing
```

**However,** if I run the same script, this time trying to get rid of the line containing `testing`, like so:

```
./script.sh | grep -v "testing"
```

**Then** the output is, as expected:

```
[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned
```

---

Now what's wrong here?? Clearly, I am using the right command, since it works in the second example. It just doesn't work to omit the actual line I want it to!

What am I missing?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also please show any attempts you've made on your own. You are expected to have made some attempts before asking.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Updated question

Comment: Square brackets are regular expression metacharacters. They mean a character class. They don't match as normal characters. You need to escape them (with `\\`) or tell grep to use fixed patterns (with `fgrep` or the `-F` flag to `grep`).

Comment: @EtanReisner - Tried both fgrep and grep -F, no dice.

Comment: What *exact* `grep -F` command did you use and on exactly what output? Run `{ ./script.sh | tee /dev/stderr | grep -vF '[1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned' | sed 's/^/stdout:/'; } 2>&1 | cat -A` please.

Comment: @EtanReisner - I ran `sudo motion | grep -v "\[1\] \[NTC\] \[NET\] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned"`

Comment: @EtanReisner - I just piped the output to `/dev/null`, but the messages still showed up on the console. That must mean that they aren't printing to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it!

The lines printing to the console were being sent on stderr, so grep wasn't even looking at anything.

The command I ran to make it work was:

```
sudo motion 2> >(grep -v "\[1\] \[NTC\] \[NET\] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned" 1>&2)
```

Comment: That's one solution. `sudo motion 2>&1 | grep ...` would also have worked (without needing the less-than-portable process substitution).